# Error: near line 91: near "RESULTS": syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to print a list of sportsmen that will look like: 'Sportsmen's name' showed the result 'result' at 'city'.

There are tables

```
CREATE TABLE COMPETITION
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    COMPETITION_NAME CHAR(30),
    WORLD_RECORD CHAR(30),
    SET_DATE VARCHAR(20)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE RESULTS
(
    SPORTSMAN_ID INT,
    RESULT VARCHAR(20),
    CITY VARCHAR(20),
    HOLD_DATE CHAR(20)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE SPORTSMAN
(
    SPORTSMAN_ID INT IDENTITY,
    SPORTSMAN_NAME CHAR(30),
    [RANK] VARCHAR(10),
    YEAR_OF_BIRTH CHAR(20),
    PERSONAL_RECORD VARCHAR(30),
    COUNTRY CHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO COMPETITION
VALUES
(21,'Первенство школы по ОФП', NULL, '1665'),
(14,'Весенние старты', 'Ангелина Мерзкая', '20-26 апреля'),
(42,'Первенство России', 'Юлия Склизкая', '26 апреля-02 мая'),
(25,'Первенство школы', 'Сергей Безруков', '8-10 мая'),
(12,'Кубок России', 'Валентин Рикунов', '14-21 мая'),
(13,'Гонки с пересадкой', 'Алексей Ширяев', '17-20 мая'),
(15,'Микро', 'Василий Шевченко', '30 мая-03 июня'),
(24,'Парусная регата', 'Максим Храмцов', '09-13 июня'),
(23,'Паруса России', 'Максим Двоеглвзов', '11-12 июня'),
(22,'Чемпионат России','Артем Цицаренко', '11-15 июля'),
(20,'Первенство Липецка', 'Александр Косолапов', '13-14 июля'),
(19,'Первенство СДЮСШОР10', 'Мария Недорезова', '13-14 июля '),
(17,'Кубок Европы', 'Владислав Мирнов', '14-18 июля'),
(16,'Первенство России 2013', '12', '1969');

INSERT INTO RESULTS
VALUES
(15, '1-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '27 января'),
(24, '2-ое место', 'г.Геленджик', '20-26 апреля'),
(35, '3-ое место', 'г.Таганрог', '26 апреля-02 мая'),
(12, '2-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '8-10 мая'),
(7, '4-ое место', 'г.Сочи', '14-21 мая '),
(8, '1-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '17-20 мая '),
(3, '3-ое место', 'г.Сочи', '30 мая-03 июня'),
(23, '4-ое место', 'Псковская обл.', '09-13 июня'),
(13, '2-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '11-12 июня'),
(9, '1-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '11-15 июля'),
(6, '4-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '13-14 июля '),
(5, '3-ое место', 'г. Тольятти', '13-14 июля '),
(2, '4-ое место', 'г.Липецк', '14-18 июля '),
(11, '3-ое место', 'г. Москва', '12-18 августа');

INSERT INTO SPORTSMAN
VALUES
(15, 'Ангелина', '2', '1991', '4 часа', 'Russia'),
(24, 'Юлия','3', '1990', '3 часа', 'UK'),
(35, 'Сергей', '3', '1990', '3 часа', 'Russia'),
(12, 'Валентин', '2', '1993', '2 часа', 'USA'),
(7, 'Алексей', '1', '1992', '1 час', 'Russia'),
(8, 'Василий', '3', '1991', '1 час', 'UK'),
(3, 'Максим', '1', '1994', '4 часа', 'Russia'),
(23, 'Максим', '2', '1993', '3 часа', 'USA'),
(13, 'Артем', '3', '1990', '2 часа', 'Sweden'),
(9, 'Александр', '2', '1991', '1 час', 'Great Britain'),
(6, 'Мария', '3', '1992', '2 часа', 'Sweden'),
(5, 'Владислав', '2', '1994', '2 часа', 'Great Britain'),
(2, 'Сергей', '3', '1942', '2 часа', 'USA');
```

This is the command:

```
SELECT SPORTSMAN.SPORTSMAN_NAME "showed the result" RESULTS.RESULT "at" RESULTS.CITY
FROM SPORTSMAN,RESULTS;
```

It prints this error:

> Error: near line 91: near "RESULTS": syntax error

The problem isn't solving when I put space before ; Task was  taken
from http://www.itmathrepetitor.ru/43-zadachi-po-sql/. Task number 26.

What should I do?

Comment: Please add the query that's giving the error clearly and also specify that you exactly want to do

Comment: Your code strongly looks like SQL Server.  Why did you tag with MySQL?

Comment: That is not how you use select query if that is what you tried

Comment: `IDENTITY` and `GO` are Microsoft SQL Server features. I've changed the question tag to reflect that. If you're really using MySQL, please let us know, but that would explain certain issues.

Comment: Aside: It's interesting that your sample `insert` statements insert `identity` values without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to join the 2 tables, but are missing a join condition (and are using an out of date join style). You are also using double quotes instead of single quotes for your string definitions. And you aren't doing anything to concatenate them (`+`).

```
SELECT S.SPORTSMAN_NAME + ' showed the result ' + R.RESULT + ' at ' + RESULTS.CITY
FROM SPORTSMAN S
INNER JOIN RESULTS R on R.SPORTSMAN_ID = S.SPORTSMAN_ID;
```

Note the use of aliases to avoid having to write the table name out in full each time.

As an aside you should always explicitly specify the column names you are inserting into as part of your insert statement. This avoids breaking your SQL when you modify the table.

Comment: It prints something like this:  1
2
3
2
4
1
3
4
2
1
4
3
4

Comment: I don't think that this is a list, that I need

Comment: Its not possible that it prints a list of numbers, because none of the columns are numeric or contain numbers? You must have done something slightly different, or have different data to posted? Or have you worked it out now?